# Criar uma função em python que retorna um número que é a quantidade de valores iguais de duas colunas

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar uma função que me retorne um número que seja a quantidade de valores iguais em duas colunas. (Sou novato em programação)

Tentei o seguinte (não sei quão errado está):

```
e = 0
df_08['cmb_mpg'] = A
df_18['cmb_mpg'] = B
def equal():
    while e < A(len):
        for b in 'B': 
            for a in 'A':
                if a == b:
                    e = e+1
return e
```

Comment: Tem como descrever linha a linha o seu código? Já adianto que ele não faz sentido, mas prefiro ver qual foi o seu raciocício ao elaborá-lo. Quem sabe seja melhor você começar estudando construção de algoritmos antes de se aventurar em uma linguagem de programação.

Comment: Pensei no seguinte: na primeira linha queria que a função fosse executada enquanto o valor de e fosse menor que o comprimento de A, depois queria procurar dentro de B, valores que se assemelhassem com A e caso essa função fosse verdadeira adicionar 1 ao e.

Comment: você sabe que quando atribui uma variável com `=` a nova variável fica do lado esquerdo não é? O sinal de `=` em Python e em quase nenhuma linguagem não é como em matemática em que ele "define" que duas coisas são iguais - ele atribuiu ao nome da esquerda o resultado daexpressão do lado direito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, tem alguns erros de sintaxe no seu código. Vou tentar lista-los.

1º - Para declarar uma variável do tipo string basta fazer:

```
nomeVariavel = "conteúdo da string"
```

2º - A sua função não está recebendo nenhum parâmetro. A função deve receber parâmetros, que serão os valores utilizados dentro da função.
Ex.:

```
def quantosIguais(a, b):
```

3º - A varíável *e*, que será utilizada como contador, deve ser declarada dentro do escopo da função.

4º - Para descobrir o tamanho da string, faz-se `len(nomeString)` e não `(len)nomeString`.

5º - Nos laços *for* que você utilizou, eles percorrem apenas 1 valor, que é a letra que você colocou. Para utilizar a variável, basta colocar o nome da variável depois do `in`. Utilizando as aspas, você percorre uma nova string, diferente da string armazenada na variável.
Faça:

```
for a in nomeString
```

ao invés de:

```
for a in 'nomeString'
```

Bom, eu tentei listar os erros de sintaxe, mas como já foi dito, seu código não faz sentido. Também gostaria de entender qual foi sua lógica pra chegar a esse código.

Vou deixar um exemplo de uma função que faça o que você tentou fazer:

```
def quantasIguais(strA, strB):
    e = 0
    for i in range(len(strA)):
        if strA[i] == strB[i]:
            e += 1
    return e
```

Comment: Legal, valeu pela excelente explicação.

Comment: Pensei o seguinte: queria fazer um loop que buscasse elementos em A e comparasse com B. Caso essa função fosse verdadeira, adicionaria 1 a e.

Comment: @VictorBoscaro essa resposta resolveu o seu problema? Se sim, a melhor maneira de agradecer é marcar ela como "resolvido"